# Function object approach safe for function pointers?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming

I'm coding on a project which makes heavy use of curried objects and templates. The new `decltype` feature of c++11 means that I could start accepting function objects that do not explicitly define a return type as the curry for my function objects. Instead, the return type could be extracted with a meta function such as:

```
template<typename func_T, typename arg1_T>
struct unary_result {
  typedef typename std::remove_reference<typename std::remove_cv<decltype(func_T()(arg1_T()))>::type>::type type;
};
```

Given a function object:

```
struct foo {
  int operator()(double) const;
};
```

(which does not inherit from `std::unary_function<double, int>` or define its `result_type`), I could just get it as `unary_result<foo, double>::type`, which works out well in my current code (for one thing, it allows the same function object to have different behavior for different parameters).

*My question is: how would this interact with function pointers?*

I am aware that STL is able to use function objects and function pointers interchangeably, but have never actually worked with function pointers, so my intuitions are not very well developed in this area. I am also aware that this might be something that is buried somewhere in Boost already (I'm sure someone will point that out very soon if this is the case).

Comment: Could you explain why you need the `decltype`? I.e. why not simply do `typedef typename std::remove_reference<std::remove_cv<func_T>::type>::type`?

Comment: That would give me `foo`, but what I want is `int`.

Comment: Function objects and function pointers can both work with () operator. But you can never actually call a function object. They are not really interchangeable.

Comment: You might be interested in `std::result_of`.

Comment: @LucDanton: thank you for pointing me to `std::result_of`! That's one less well to implement! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `unary_result` should work just fine with function pointers, though you need an extra `typename` before `std::remove_cv`.

Example:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename func_T, typename arg1_T>
struct unary_result {
  typedef typename std::remove_reference<typename std::remove_cv<decltype(func_T()(arg1_T()))>::type>::type type;
};

struct foo {
    int operator()(double d) const
    {
        return d;
    }

};

int bar(int i){
    return i;
}

template<typename Func,typename Arg>
typename unary_result<Func,Arg>::type do_stuff(Func f,Arg a){
    return f(a);
}

int main(){
    int i=do_stuff(bar,42);
    int d=do_stuff(foo(),3.1);
}
```

Comment: Can you give a working code example that passes both a function object and a function pointer to unary_result?